# IPython, prompt each time before closing the terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal, ipython

I am using IPython 1.2.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. I have checked all the settings and profile preferences, but I cannot find a command which would prompt each time I close the window.

How I can make IPython prompt me each time before I close the terminal?

Sometimes, by mistake, I close the terminal and every graph that was opened by the terminal get lost.

Comment: Sounds more like a terminal problem, I don't think IPython can influence what happens when you click on the X to close the terminal window. For me, however, the terminal does prompt a message if any process is still running.

Comment: @swenzel: what if I have already run some code and produced figures which I need?

Comment: Hmm, the only way I can see how the prompt is suppressed is if the process is suspended or running in background. Do you use Ctrl + Z to end IPython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it in the config file.  The location of this file depends on your platform, version, your user profile and how you installed IPython.

For example, on one of my boxes (Linux, pretty much default installation, v3.1.0), it is located at `$HOME/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`

This file looks like

```
c = get_config()
... ...
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.confirm_exit = False
```

for my installation and user profile.  You can set this flag to `True`.

---

Edit:  This is only effective if you exit by feeding the interactive interpreter the EOF character (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>).  If you quit by typing `quit` or `exit`, it has no effect.  If you kill your terminal emulator containing a live session, well, you get what you deserve ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ipython) this should do it:

```
-[no]confirm_exit
    Set to confirm when you try to exit IPython with an EOF 
    (Control-D in Unix, Control-Z/Enter in Windows). Note 
    that using the magic functions @Exit or @Quit you can 
    force a direct exit, bypassing any confirmation.
```

For example, to enable confirmation before exiting:

```
$ ipython -confirm_exit
```

That version seems a little old. I'm running v2.3.0 on Cygwin.

Comment: can you explain a bit further, I don't totally understand

Comment: It's a command line argument to the tool. I've updated by answer with example usage.